# How to add posix hooks under linux?

Tags: linux, overriding, hook, posix

I was considering adding some custom security behaviour to the posix APIs of a distro of linux I'm working on.

For example, prompting the user to authenticate if a program asks to fopen() a directory it has write access to, but should not normally access.

Is there an easy way to hook custome behaviour in to a posix call before making the native linux call, or do I just have to branch my own source, and drop a function into the actual library before, performing the standard behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LD_PRELOAD to load up your own library before the other system libraries. Through this you can write some sort of wrapper fopen() etc. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) link for more info.